# send merg tag from local database to mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

I'am new to mailchimp. While working on mailchimp I'm stuck on a point,can anyone tell me  how to pass merge tags from our local database to mailchimp.

Thanks 
Anurodh

Answer (score 2):

Lists in MailChimp start with a default set of merge tags LNAME, FNAME, EMAIL...

From there you can add any number of custom merge tags you want...

use the listMergeVarAdd method to add a merge var via the API
http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listmergevaradd.func.php

You can also use the listMergeVars to get the merge variables associated with a specific list

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listmergevars.func.php

Beyond that you can manually set the merge vars via the MailChimp website...

Once you have that you can then pass the member informatoin from your database to the mailchimp site via api calls (either listSubscribe or listUpdateMember)

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listupdatemember.func.php